# Do or do not use Ruby on Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

I am new in RoR , and I wanted to design a web based system. I want to know , if we don't use association in RoR , do happen any problem in system? 
Please help me and explain me what problem could be happen in such a system.
thanks

Comment: Rails guides has explained this well. They describe the advantages and disadvantages both with clear and simple examples. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The associations that Rails provides you gives some methods that would make your querying simpler, more readable, maintainable and effective.

Try writing two versions of a Customer-Orders application and then Customer-Order-Supplier 1) with associations and the other without and perform some different type of queries and see the beauty of queries where associations was exploited. From the queries executed you can also see the time they take from the Rails log. Then go into some more complicated examples to delve deeper. You can find some simple examples to start with in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).